# MongoDB GridFS delete operation too slow while mongod process takes up 100% CPU

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo, gridfs

I'm using Python (CPython 2.7.3 on Debian 7.8 amd64) with `pymongo` driver (version 2.7.2) to connect to a MongoDB (db version v2.4.12) database which has solely been used to store files in a GridFS storage collection. While mongodb can find the `_id` of a file object with a given `filename` instantaneously, requesting to delete that file given its `_id` takes an unusual 10s of seconds to complete during which `mongod` takes up 100% CPU time.

I'm not a mongodb expert and have not done any performance optimizations on it, but still I think there is something wrong here. What am I missing and how can I pinpoint and solve this problem?

I should add that there are millions of files in this collection with nearly 700GB size, and the free space left on disk is running very low.

Comment: Could you show the query you are performing against the database?

Comment: first `fileobj = GridFS.get_version(filename=filename, version=-1)` to query for file object and then `GridFS.delete(fileobj._id)` to delete.

Comment: Are there any slow queries in the server logs for the delete operation? If so, could you post them? Have you tried using mongostat to monitor a deletion operation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and resolved it by adding indexes that speed up GridFS substantially.
The commands to add the index are :

```
db.fs.chunks.createIndex( { files_id: 1, n: 1 }, { unique: true } );  // This allows GridFS to find the chunks in order very quickly.
```

AND

```
db.fs.files.createIndex( { filename: 1, uploadDate: 1 } );  // This allows GridFS to find the files quickly.
```

With a collection of that size, it will take a while for the indexes to create.    Happy mongoing.